# How to manipulate chrome DOM file to listen if a tab, window or screen is being shared on a google meet

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm building an extension for chrome and i want it to act differently when I select present a tab and act differently when i present my full screen or window.

How do I achieve this. What changes should I listen for? Any resources would help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.